# htaccess make alias and rewrite rule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have html in /html/test-html/index.html here. There are also css and images like this one: /html/test-html/css/style.css

When I open index.html in browser styles and images are loaded correctly.

When I'm trying to render it's contents by php echo function I get problems with 404 error, because paths in index.html and style.css are relative, like this one:

```
<link src="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

So when I echo index.html contents in my script (i.e. by url like http://localhost/product1) browser tries to find style.css by this url:

```
http://localhost/css/style.css
```

But actually file is located in

```
/html/test-html/css/style.css
```

I think that good idea is to simulate URL like browser in http://localhost/html/test-html/, but actually we are in http://localhost/product1 (with RewriteRule), but without a redirect.

In other words, I want browser to think that http://localhost/product1 is http://localhost/test-html and server to think that http://localhost/product1 is http://localhost/index.php?r=product/view&id=1

Is it possible?

Comment: Just use paths that are relative to the domain root - starting with a `/`. If portability (as concerning installation/URL path flexibility) is an issue, then use a constant to be used as a base path wherever URLs are created/output. (And of course make your rewriting leave requests for files that exist on the hard drive untouched.)

Comment: @CBroe, it is impossible, there are a lot of media includes in htmls and there are a lot of htmls. Also, htmls should be available as usual html files and as product of rendering in a script. Comlex task.
In a previous version of a project I realized this task with extra folder in path, like http://localhost/product/product1, but now I have to remove /product/ from path

Comment: Well as an alternative you could try and use the `base` element; maybe you can even figure out what the appropriate value should be automatically most times. (I'm personally not a huge fan of that method, it can make up for some nasty surprises, but YMMV.)

Comment: I'm using <iframe> as alternative, it allows to work with contents as usual, but uses it's own paths.